# WordPress: Get custom post type category link in `have_posts` loop

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I get the custom post type category link in the while `have_posts` loop?

Here is the code I am using to get the category name:

```php
<?php query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio'
)); ?>
           <?php while (have_posts()):
    the_post(); ?>
               <?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-3-portfolio">
            <div class="portfoliobox">
                <img src="<?php echo $feat_image; ?>" />
                   <div class="portfolio-title-block">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
           <?php
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'portfolio-category');
    if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)):
        $tslugs_arr = array();
        foreach ($terms as $term)
        {
            $tslugs_arr[] = $term->slug;
        }
        $terms_slug_str = join(" ", $tslugs_arr);
    endif;
    $idObj = get_category_by_slug('portfolio-category');
    $id = $idObj->term_id;
?>
                    <p><a href="<?php get_category_link($id); ?> "><?php echo $terms_slug_str; ?></a></p>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <?php
endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: use get_term_link function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link